# Gulp.js create a zip with a version suffix in the name, but keep original name inside

Tags: node.js, zip, gulp

I'm trying to figure out how to pack a zip fille from a folder with a version suffix, but keep the original name of the folder when the archive is being extracted. It's a wp theme. So `theme-1.5.0.zip` must extract a folder named `theme`. But this code extracts it like `theme-1.5.0`

```
gulp.task('make-zip', function () {
  return gulp.src('build/theme/**')
  .pipe(zip('theme-'+version+'.zip'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

When I compress `theme` folder manually in finder and then rename `theme.zip` to `theme-1.5.0.zip` it actually keeps the original name inside. But not if it was compressed with gulp.

Thanks!

Comment: So, I've removed my answer since doesn't add nothing to the response. About what you want. I don't know if you can do that, since, by default the uncompress folder takes the file name, unless the user, specifies otherwise. I'll keep an eye here to see if someone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself. Ultimately I was able to get it work by setting a base path to the src.

```
gulp.task('make-zip', function () {
  return gulp.src('build/theme/**', {base: "build"})
  .pipe(zip('theme-'+version+'.zip'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

Comment: One year later, I revisit this question of mine to find out that this is actually a correct answer.